# how to change a existing analyzer in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Now that's existing analyzer：

`"analyzer": {
  "xmap_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "char_filter": [ "html_strip"],
    "filter": [ "lowercase"],
    "tokenizer": "standard"
  }
}`

I want to remove "filter", and it'll be this:

`"analyzer": {
  "xmap_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "char_filter": [ "html_strip"],
    "tokenizer": "standard"
  }
}`

I have tried to update the settings, like this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis

But it's invalid, how should I do?

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried and the output of said code?

Comment: Have you closed the index first?

Comment: I have closed the index, and output of side is true